# How we call the server side function on confirm ok click

Tags: asp.net

I want to call the server side function on confirm ok click but i am do this please give the way how i do this
The Html Code is

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="btnMsg" runat="server" OnClick="btnMsg_Click" Text="popup" />
<p id="demo">jjj</p>
</div>
```

The server side code is

```
protected void btnMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("var x=''; var r=confirm('Press a button!');");
            sb.Append("if (r==true){Save();}");
            sb.Append("else{ alert('cancel');}");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString(), true);
```

The save function is

```
 public void save()
        {
            string a = "Farrukh";
        }
```

But sir this function not call give the way how i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

if you press yes in confirm box it will automatically call server side `Save()` method.

```
  <script>
function myconfirmfunction()
{
var x=''; 
var r=confirm('Press a button!');

if (r)
{
alert('hi');
return true;
}
else{ 
return false;
    }
}
</script>


 <asp:Button ID="btnMsg" runat="server" OnClick="btnMsg_Click" 
OnClientClick="return myconfirmfunction();" Text="popup" />
```

Server side:

```
protected void btnMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 save();

}
```

**Update:**

server side Solution:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"function myconfirmfunction()
                    {
                    var x=''; 
                    var r=confirm('Press a button!');

                    if (r)
                    {
                    alert('hi');
                    return true;
                    }
                    else{ 
                    return false;
                        }
                    }", true);
    }
    protected void btnMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Data Saved Successfully.');", true);

    }
```

Comment: but with this no confirmation box open for for ask ok or cancel

Comment: save function always call when on button click but i want to call only on confirm yes click

Comment: @farrukh check updated answer , may due to  wrong `script` tag

Comment: sir can u guide me how i call a function on confirm ok

Comment: with this every time the save function call but i want to call the save function on confirm ok click

Comment: sir its working you are right but i want to use the server side confirm as i use above .....but only one problem to call the function when click on ok of confirm please guide how i call the function in above code which i use

Comment: sir when javascript off then its not work which you give me

Comment: Yes you need to turn on JavaScript for your browser

Comment: sir but i do this when javascript off please tell me if u how to call function when on above code which i give u

Comment: We cant run JavaScript if is disabled on browser

Comment: how sir i do this